# Pyinstaller не компилирует библиотеки которые указаны в файле

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, пробую сделать exe из кода python, код компилируется но когда запускаю проблему вылезает ошибка что нужная библиотека не найдена, не могу понять в чем проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

компилирую через auto-py-exe (графическая оболочка pyinstaller)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор запускаю из виртуальной среды, где установлены все библиотеки.
Может как то можно принудительно указать нужные библиотеки?

Comment: Попробуйте указать не "Одна папка", а "Один файл".